# Checking Nameserver setup from command line

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, command-line-interface, nameserver

Is there a way to check if my domain is setup correctly on the nameservers? Ideally I'd like to run a command from command line, alternatively can use a third party tool.

for example, I'm trying to register a domain that's to be hosted on godaddy.com. I have set up the domain and can see it in my DNS list. The servers that are supposed to be setup are ns51.domaincontrol.com and ns52.domaincontrol.com, however my registration is bouncing saying that there are "No Nameservers found for {my new domain}".

Answer (score 2):

To attempt a transfer of the zone from a 3rd party provider (great way to see a nameserver is configured to answer for the zone, but will only work if they don't have an ACL on transfers):

```
dig AXFR <zone> [@nameserver]
```

ie,

```
dig ZXFR my-new-domain.tld @ns51.domaincontrol.com
```

If you are hosting the zone yourself and are using BIND you can use named-checkzone to check the validity of your zone and named-checkconf to check the validity of your overall config.

I am unfamiliar with any domain registrars who will bounce your registration for not having the zone already configured on the destination nameserver; they can, however, bounce your registration if you don't provide nameservers, or if the nameservers you provide haven't been properly defined.

Comment: Some TLDs (like .FR) require a successful technical check before the DNS publication take place.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, use the **nslookup** command:

```
nslookup
server ns51.domaincontrol.com
yourdomain.com
set type=soa
yourdomain.com
set type=ns
yourdomain.com
server ns52.domaincontrol.com
yourdomain.com
set type=soa
yourdomain.com
set type=ns
yourdomain.com
```

You should get positive responses back on all queries.  The SOA lookup should list one of the domaincontrol.com NS server as the primary and the NS lookup should list both ns51 and ns52.

Comment: Quite painful to do all of this by hand.

Comment: +1 using built-in tools in windows is always the best. I also like to use set type=all which gives you the lot in one go

Comment: It would be better and easier to install dig and use that.

Comment: I don't disagree with you John. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Zonecheck](http://www.zonecheck.fr/) is a free software and can be run from the command line:

```
% zonecheck stackoverflow.com
ZONE  : stackoverflow.com.
NS <= : ns51.domaincontrol.com. [216.69.185.26]
NS    : ns52.domaincontrol.com. [208.109.255.26]

       _______________
     ,---------------.|
~~~~ |    warning    || ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     `---------------'
w> Nameservers are all part of the same AS
 | Adv: ZoneCheck
 |   To avoid losing all connectivity with the authoritative DNS in case
 | of a routing problem inside your Autonomous System, it is advised to
 | host the DNS on different AS.
 `----- -- -- - -  -
 :   All the nameservers are part of the same Autonomous System (AS number
 : 26496), try to have some of them hosted on another AS.
 `..... .. .. . .  .
=> generic

==> SUCCESS (but 1 warning(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using nslookup. Alternatively you could use DNSStuff or another web site that performs DNS testing. If this domain is new it may take awhile for the gTLD name servers for .com to get the info about your domain from GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **short and quick** command to list your nameservers:

```
host -t ns yourdomain.com
```